# how to convert javascript function to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a javascript function. Which does the show/hide in onChange. I would like to convert it in jquery, how to do it.

Javacript function

```
function assocWindowOnLoad()
      {
          var option=document.getElementsByName("select_id");
          document.getElementById('conent1').style.display='none';
          document.getElementById('conent2').style.display='none';
      }

function assocWindowOnChange(val)
    {
          //if user select option Select from drop down
          if(val=='')
          {   
              //alert("Please Select option from the dropdown");
          assocWindowOnLoad();
          }
          else
          {
              //Show or hide piece of code depending on user input
              document.getElementById('conent1').style.display=(val=='no')?'none':'block';
              document.getElementById('conent2').style.display=(val=='no')?'block':'none';
          }
      }
```

HTML Code

```
<body onLoad="assocWindowOnLoad();">
<select name="select_id" id="select_id" onChange="assocWindowOnChange(this.value);" >
           <option value='' selected="selected">Select</option>
           <option value='no'>1st Option</option>
           <option value='yes'>Second Option</option>
</select>

<div id="conent1" class="hide">

<p>some content</p>

</div>

<div id="conent1" class="hide">

<p>some content</p>

</div>

<div id="conent2" class="hide">

<p>some content</p>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `hide() and show()` method of jquery..

```
function assocWindowOnLoad()       {
    $('#conent1').hide();
    $('#conent2').hide();
}

function assocWindowOnChange(val){
    //if user select option Select from drop down
    if(val==''){
        //alert("Please Select option from the dropdown");
        assocWindowOnLoad();
    }else{
        //Show or hide piece of code depending on user input
        if(val=='no'){
            $('#conent1').hide();
            $('#conent2').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#conent1').show();
            $('#conent2').hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    // To hide the element
    $("YOUR_SELCTOR").click(function()
    {
       $("ELEMENT_TO_BE_HIDE").hide("slow");
    });

    // To show the element
    $("YOUR_SELCTOR").click(function()
    {
       $("ELEMENT_TO_BE_HIDE").show("slow");
    });


});
```

You can use `toggle()` in place of `hide` and `show`.

Answer (score 0):

```
toggleDisplay = function() {
  if($('#select_id').val()=='no'){
    $('#conent1').hide();
    $('#conent2').show();
  } else {
     $('#conent1').show();
     $('#conent2').hide();
  }

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    toggleDisplay();
    $('#select_id').change(function() {
      toggleDisplay();
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks for your code, my target is not to use any js function like onChange. Everything has to be control by jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $("select #myselectid").change(function () {
   var str = "";
   var value = $(this).val();
   if (value == 'yes') {
     $('conent1').hide();
     $('conent2').show();
   }
   else {
     $('conent1').show();
     $('conent2').hide();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need 
http://docs.jquery.com/index.php?title=Core/fn.extend . Just extend the jquery plugin with your own function.